# Nginx does not receive request with specific url

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, vagrant

I have a server block with the following configuration (default [Laravel Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/homestead) configuration).

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name site.app;
    root "/home/vagrant/projects/site/public";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log on;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/site.app-error.log;

    sendfile off;

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/site.app.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/site.app.key;
}
```

It seems every route is working except the following:

```
http://site.app:8000/backend
```

Tailing the access logs shows that Nginx never receives the request. Strangely, adding a trailing `/` works without any problems. So the following url works:

```
http://site.app:8000/backend/
```

#### Additional information:

Nginx version: 1.11.1

My public folder has `index.php` and an `assets/backend` directory. Deleting that directory doesn't seem to do anything, however.

Comment: That URL is for a service running on port 8000. The configuration you provide shows that `nginx` is running on ports 80 and 443. What are you running on port 8000?

Comment: The port is forwarded to port 80 in the virtual machine. As I said, all other requests work as expected, excluding that one specific url.

Answer (score 0):

It was a caching issue with my Chrome browser. I'm not sure exactly what happened but my guess is that Chrome cached the failed request when there was a `backend` directory at the web root. It seems Nginx doesn't respond to requests that attempt to access a directory.